# I would like to track inventory level in my store based on sell through. I have data in excel format

Tags: php, vb.net, excel

I need help regarding inventory management in my stores. I have 30 stores in the city. I get weekly sales report in excel. I am using excel filters to find the stocks in these 30 stores. Its a hard work for me cos every year no of store getting raised.

Please help me, I have excel sales report. We will calculate based on sell through percentage. 
For eg. I sent a 10pcs of Product A to store X. And the weekly report says that 6pcs of Product A sold in store x. So the sell through percentage is 60% and the stock in store X reduced to 4pcs of Product A. So from the warehouse I have to send 6 more pieces to store x immediately. This is for one store is okay. But for 30 stores how many filters i have to use. I used to miss datas many times. Please help me how can i solve this problem?

Thank in advance

Answer (score 0):

Nobody is going to give a quick solution to this. But I can give you guidance.

You need to stop doing it this way and come up with a demand planning system. Of course your going to miss things doing it like this.

You need to break the problem into many small steps and have a worksheet for each.

The sheets you should consider are

```
stores
items
store item listing
sales history
current stock
forecast
analysis 
output
```

Then what you are doing in your head, break down into each sheet using a mix of lookups,simple calculations and pivot tables)

Then the output sheet will have the things your need to order

Answer (score 0):

From your description and the growth you allude to it may be that supply chain and inventory specific software is what you need. Eventually you may need to train someone else to do this and when you get there a home brew solution in Excel may not be as easily migrated to a multi user environment.

You really could do a lot of this in Excel, but you might get more bang for your buck looking at something else that can import Excel data and generate the activity analysis you need.